# Extracting and save relevant data from a txt file

Tags: vb.net

I tried to write a code but I didn't succeed at all. Could someone help me please?

I want my program to read the `data.txt` file

The data.txt file contains:

```
Name: Christian
Phone: x
Address: x
Name: Alexander
Phone: x
Address: x
```

I would like the program to save the names in a output file: `output_data.txt`

The output_data.txt file should be contain:

```
Christian
Alexander
```

This is what I have so far:

```vb
Using DataReader As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser("data.txt")
    Dim DataSaver As System.IO.StreamWriter
    DataReader.TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
    DataReader.SetDelimiters("Name: ")
    Dim Row As String()
    While Not DataReader.EndOfData
        Row = DataReader.ReadFields()
        Dim DataSplited As String
        For Each DataSplited In Row
            My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("output_data.txt", DataSplited, False)
            'MsgBox(DataSplited)
        Next
    End While
End Using
```

But the `output_data.txt` file does not save properly to what "MsgBox (DataSplited)" shows. MsgBox(DataSplit) delimits the name by Name: but also shows the rest, such as address, phone. I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: Let us see what you have tried. We don't know if your problem is reading the file, parsing the file or writing a new file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will work:

```
    Dim strFile = "c:\test5\data.txt"
    Dim InputBuf As String = File.ReadAllText(strFile)
    Dim OutBuf As String = ""

    Dim InBufHold() As String = Split(InputBuf, "Name:")
    For i = 1 To InBufHold.Length - 1
        OutBuf += Trim(Split(InBufHold(i), vbCrLf)(0)) & vbCrLf
    Next

    File.WriteAllText("c:\test5\output_data.txt", OutBuf)
```

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Dim names = File.ReadLines("data.txt").
            Where(Function(line) line.StartsWith("Name: ")).
            Select(Function(line) line.SubString(5).Trim())
File.WriteAllText("output_data.txt", String.Join(vbCrLf, names))
```